# problem passing in istream argument to a class constructor

Tags: c++

I have the following code in my header file:

```
class Factovisors {

    public:
        Factovisors(std::istream& strm):strm_(strm)
        {

        }
        void run()
        {
            unsigned int n,m;
            while (!strm_.eof()) {
            strm_ >> n >> m;

            if (isFact(n,m))
                std::cout << m << " divides " << n << "!\n";
            }
        }

        std::istream strm_;

};
```

My .cpp file has the following code.

```
 std::ifstream strm("factovisor.test");

    Factovisors   facto(strm);

    facto.run();

    strm.close();
```

The error my compiler gives me is:

```
std::ios::basic_ios(const std::ios &) is not accessible from
std::istream::basic_istream(const std::istream &)
```

I imagine I am missing something really obvious. So any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is that `istream` is an "interface". It has pure virtual functions, so it doesn't make sense to have a copy of it. What you might do is to keep a reference to the passed stream:

```
std::istream& strm_;
```

`strm_` could be `ifstream` or `istringstream` or any input stream derived from `istream`.

Answer (score 2):

You can't copy-construct a stream because the base-class ios has its copy ctor private.  Try making the stream member a reference, rather than a standalone object.

Answer (score 2):

You are trying to store a copy of the stream. This will not work, since streams are not copyable. Best you can do is store a reference or a pointer.

However, if only one method is going to use the stream, just pass a reference to this method.

Other problems:

```
        while (!strm_.eof()) {
        strm_ >> n >> m;

        if (isFact(n,m))
```

Eof is set when an attempt to read data fails because of this. As it is you are bound to read the last entry twice. Instead:

```
while (strm >> n >> m )
    if (isFact(n, m)
```